# How to tell RPM to ignore non-installed packages upon rpm --erase?

Tags: rpm

I have a list of 30 or so "undesired" packages that I always erase/delete/remove on a newly installed RPM-based Linux system.

However, when I try the `--erase` command, e.g. (intentionally shortened)

```
# rpm -e sos abrt abrt-libs abrt-python abrt-dbus abrt-addon-xorg abrt-tui abrt-addon-ccpp abrt-cli abrt-console-notification abrt-addon-kerneloops abrt-retrace-client abrt-addon-vmcore abrt-addon-pstoreoops abrt-addon-python
error: package abrt is not installed
error: package abrt-libs is not installed
error: package abrt-python is not installed
error: package abrt-dbus is not installed
error: package abrt-addon-xorg is not installed
error: package abrt-tui is not installed
error: package abrt-addon-ccpp is not installed
error: package abrt-cli is not installed
error: package abrt-console-notification is not installed
error: package abrt-addon-kerneloops is not installed
error: package abrt-retrace-client is not installed
error: package abrt-addon-vmcore is not installed
error: package abrt-addon-pstoreoops is not installed
error: package abrt-addon-python is not installed
Exit 14
```

Some package(s) (`sos` only I guess?) apparently do exist but are not erased.  Naturally I do not want to match the two package lists (mine and the error messages) and edit the commandline because it takes too long even in this short example.

So of course I could try to work around it like

```
echo sos abrt abrt-libs abrt-python abrt-dbus abrt-addon-xorg abrt-tui abrt-addon-ccpp abrt-cli abrt-console-notification abrt-addon-kerneloops abrt-retrace-client abrt-addon-vmcore abrt-addon-pstoreoops abrt-addon-python | xargs --max-args=1 rpm -e
```

but I would rather ignore non-existing packages.

How do I do that?  `--force` does not work on erase:

```
# rpm -e --force sos abrt abrt-libs abrt-python abrt-dbus abrt-addon-xorg abrt-tui abrt-addon-ccpp abrt-cli abrt-console-notification abrt-addon-kerneloops abrt-retrace-client abrt-addon-vmcore abrt-addon-pstoreoops abrt-addon-python
rpm: only installation and upgrading may be forced
Exit 1
```

Comment: Please use `rpm -qa | grep abrt` to decide package names.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Tnanks. I am looking for a way to ignore non-installed packages when erasing.  The list of packages is very long.

Comment: Usually you do actually not use `# rpm -e` to remove a package. The right way is `yum remove [package]` , `dnf remove [package]` , `zypper remove [package]` ... or whatever package manager installed the packages.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I did try that but `yum` suggested the removal of dozens of other packages because it recursively selected soft dependencies. I couldn't use it.

Comment: The usual "1000" system packages cannot be removed : The OS will stop being usable.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Removing the packages listed above works perfectly. This question is about the `rpm` command.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you were looking for. This version just ouputs a list of packages that matched what was installed.

```bash
#- for pkg in sos abrt abrt-libs abrt-python abrt-dbus abrt-addon-xorg abrt-tui abrt-addon-ccpp abrt-cli abrt-console-notification abrt-addon-kerneloops abrt-retrace-client abrt-addon-vmcore abrt-addon-pstoreoops abrt-addon-python; do rpm --quiet -q "$pkg" && echo "$pkg"; done
abrt
abrt-libs
abrt-dbus
abrt-addon-xorg
abrt-tui
abrt-addon-ccpp
abrt-cli
abrt-console-notification
abrt-addon-kerneloops
abrt-retrace-client
abrt-addon-vmcore
abrt-addon-pstoreoops
```

You can use the above to generate a list of package names that can then be fed back into `rpm` for erasure (aka removal):

```bash
#- rpm -e --nodeps $(for pkg in sos abrt abrt-libs abrt-python abrt-dbus abrt-addon-xorg abrt-tui abrt-addon-ccpp abrt-cli abrt-console-notification abrt-addon-kerneloops abrt-retrace-client abrt-addon-vmcore abrt-addon-pstoreoops abrt-addon-python; do rpm --quiet -q "$pkg" && echo "$pkg"; done)
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrt-journal-core.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrt-xorg.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrt-vmcore.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrt-oops.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrtd.service.
```

Note this simple version does not handle dependency processing. If you need to handle dependencies you should probably just switch to DNF (or YUM) since that is what those tools were created to do.